# Optimizing a function of a quadratic polynomial

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, convex-optimization

Given an $m \times n$ real, non-negative data matrix $X$ I want to find coefficients $a\in \mathbb{R},b\in\mathbb{R},$ and $c \in \mathbb{R}: c\neq -1$
that minimize

$$f\left(\frac{a+bX+cX^2}{1+c}\right).$$

with the constraint that $\frac{a+bX_{ij}+cX^2_{ij}}{1+c} \geq 0\, \forall (i,j) \in \{1,2\ldots, m\}\times\{1,2,\ldots ,n\}$.

In brief, $f(M)$ is the Kolmogorov-Smirnov distance computed in the singular values of a scaled version of $M$ against a target distribution.

We have successfully solved a smaller version of this problem by removing the constant term $a$ and restricting to $b\geq 0, c\geq 0$. We minimize $$f\left( \sigma^2((1-q)X+qX^2)\right )$$ for $q\in [0,1]$. In this scheme, we optimize over the convex coefficient $q$, and for every value of $q$ there is a unique scaling coefficient $\sigma$ that minimizes $f$ and can be computed from the spectrum of $(1-q)X+qX^2$. We compute the minimum by approximating $f$ with Chebyshev, and then $b$ and $c$ can be computed by substitution.

Is there any hope for minimizing my problem in three variables or with the relaxation that $b$ and $c$ can be negative?

Edit: A "dumb" approach would be to just extend the Chebyshev approximation into multiple dimensions, but because $f$ is a function of the spectrum of its input, this is costly to compute.